# What is the name of this group?

Tags: group-theory

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field and consider the set $\mathbb{K}^2$ of ordered pairs and define multiplication by
$$
(z_1, z_2) \cdot (w_1, w_2) = (z_1w_1 + z_2w_2, z_1w_2 + z_2w_1).
$$

Then the elements $(z_1, z_2)$ of $\mathbb{K}^2$ such that $z_1 \neq \pm z_2$ form a group with the above multiplication.

Proof:
Let $(z_1, z_2), (w_1, w_2) \in \mathbb{K}^2$ such that $z_1 \neq \pm z_2$ and $w_1 \neq \pm w_2$.  Then if $z_1w_1 + z_2w_2 = z_1w_2 + z_2w_1$, then
$$
z_1 ( w_1 - w_2) = z_2 (w_1 - w_2) 
$$
but $w_1 \neq w_2$ so divide it out.  Your left with $z_1 = z_2$ which can't be by assumption, so the described set is closed under multiplication.  A similar argument takes care of the $z_1w_1 + z_2w_2 = -(z_1w_2 + z_2w_1)$ case.

The reader can verify that $(1, 0)$ is the identity element.

To find a formula for the inverse of an element, we would need
$$
(z_1w_1 + z_2w_2, z_1w_2 + z_2w_1) = (1, 0)
$$

which is iff $z_1 = -z_2w_1/w_2$, etc.  Substituting $z_1$ in the first component gives $-w_1^2 z_2 / w_2 + z_2 w_2 = 1$ or $z_2 = w_2 / (w_2^2 - w_1^2)$.  So the inverse of $(w_1, w_2)$ is $\frac{1}{w_2^2 - w_1^2}(-w_1, w_2)$.

My question is what is the common name for this group?

Thanks.

Comment: The OP is asking for a name, but the question needs editing as all it says is $\mathbb K$ is a field. Not a word about what field or even its characteristic. What if ${\mathbb K} = {\mathbb F}_2$ so ${\mathbb K}\times{\mathbb K}$ has 4 elements and only 2 off diagonal elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{R}$, these are the [split-complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number) numbers.

The ring would be more commonly expressed as adjoining an element $h$ satisfying $h^2 = 1$; i.e. as the ring $\mathbb{K}[x] / (x^2 - 1)$.

A change of basis identifies this ring with the cartesian product $\mathbb{K} \times \mathbb{K}$. Accordingly, its group of units is isomorphic to $\mathbb{K}^* \times \mathbb{K}^*$.